# "select" in C socket

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

Sorry if my question is trivial.

I am using select() in my server program to look for new connections as well as for data on exisitng connections. However, when I get data on one connection/socket, my program reads the data and store it, in an array. Here, The server will not reply back to client [ though client is in recv() mode ] .  Now, when server goes back to select() call, it is getting stuck there. Not sure why.  My intention is that, server should come out of select [ if there is no data ]. I kept timeout on the select() as well.

Any suggestions in this regards, would be of great help.

Comment: Are you re-initializing the `fd_set`'s every time in your select loop =

Comment: No. Iam not. Is it required ?

Comment: Yes. After `select` returns, the only members in the `fd_set` will be those which were ready. That's how `select` indicates to you which were ready.

Comment: Guys, i got it resolved. Seems the timeout was not working fine earlier. I have fixed it. It is working fine now..Thanks to all. If i have any doubts, will ping back you guys.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Roopesh: My suggestion is to either delete the question or add an answer yourself and set that as the accepted one (it's really your choice). That way, this question won't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it resolved. Seems the timeout was not working fine earlier. I have fixed it. It is working fine now. Thanks to all. If i have any doubts, will ping back you all.

Comment: maybe you could mark this answer as "accepted", so the question doesn't continue to show up as unanswered. cheers :-)

Comment: Yes Lee.. But when i selected it as "accepted", it is saying, you can accept your own answer only after 2 days. So, will do it, after 2 days.